# Convergence of a sequence $a_n$ (corrected version)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence such that $ a_{2n-1} \leq a_{2n+1} \leq a_{2n+2} \leq a_{2n} \forall n\geq 1$. Prove that $(a_{n})$ converges if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n}-a_{n+1}) = 0$.

My work so far involves using subsequences and showing that the even indexed terms (call them the subsequence $\{a_{n_{2k}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$) are monotonously decreasing and bounded below by $a_3$ while the odd indexed terms (call them $\{a_{n_{2k+1}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$) are monotonously increasing and bounded above by $a_4$.

Also, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, the subsequences $\{a_{n_{2k}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{a_{n_{2k+1}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to the same limit as $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ if $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, right? (I'm asking because the theorem only asserts that every bounded sequence has one convergent subsequence).

Comment: You’ve shown that the odd and even indexed subsequences converge. You can’t now apply Bolzano-Weierestrass assuming the full sequence converges because that is what you need to prove. Now use the hypothesis $a_{n+1} -a_n \to 0$ to show that the subsequences converge to the same limit. The reverse implication is easy to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: the only if part is trivial. For the if part, note that the odd terms are increasing and the even terms are decreasing. So $\limsup a_n=\underset{n\to \infty}\lim a_{2n+1}=l$ and $\liminf a_n=\underset{n\to \infty}\lim a_{2n}=m\ $  (in theory, $l$ and/or $m$ need not be finite). Now, there is an integer $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_{2n+1}-l|<\epsilon,\ |a_{2n}-m|<\epsilon$ and $|a_n-a_{n-1}|<\epsilon.$ Conclude that $l=m<\infty.$